# How to send different datas from one screen to different locations on another screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing a problem with my flutter code and can't find a solution for my problem. I wrote a simple app to show you my problem.

There are two screens: the home_screen and a dataEntry_screen. On the home_screen there are two fields: 'Age' and 'Height'. If I touch the field 'Age' it opens the dataEntry_screen where I can type in a string and when I press 'send data to home_screen' it will display the string on the 'Age' field.
To pass data between this two pages isn't the actual problem. However when I touch the 'Height' field, it shall open the same dataEntry_screen where I can make an input which will then be send to the 'Height' field.

I've tried different approaches but nothing worked. If I make an entry on the dataEntry_page and press 'send data to home_screen' the data will be displayed on both the 'Age' and the 'Height' screen. I understand why the code behaves like this, but I don't have any idea how to make it work like it should: to tab on each field, which opens the dataEntry_screen and send different data to each field from the same 'dataEntry_screen'.

The attached code is just a sample code which describes the problem. My actual app has several different fields and as I don't like the standard keyboard to enter data, I designed my own keyboard which I want to use to make entries to different fields. I hope you can understand my problem as I am pretty new to programming.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home_screen.dart';
import 'dataEntry_screen.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(initialRoute: HomeScreen.id, routes: {
  HomeScreen.id: (context) => HomeScreen(),
  DataEntryScreen.id: (context) => DataEntryScreen(),
    });
  }
}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:senddatastackoverflow/dataEntry_screen.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
HomeScreen({this.firstDataToReceive, this.secondDataToReceive});
final String firstDataToReceive;
final String secondDataToReceive;

static String id = 'home_screen';

String firstData = '';
String secondData = '';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
      Text('Age:'),
      Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => DataEntryScreen(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.grey,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child:
                Text(firstDataToReceive == null ? '' : firstDataToReceive),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 50,
      ),
      Text('Height:'),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => DataEntryScreen(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 50,
          color: Colors.grey,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child:
              Text(secondDataToReceive == null ? '' : secondDataToReceive),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:senddatastackoverflow/home_screen.dart';

class DataEntryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
static String id = 'dataEntry_screen';
@override
_DataEntryScreenState createState() => _DataEntryScreenState();
}

class _DataEntryScreenState extends State<DataEntryScreen> {
String data1;
String data2;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: TextField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                data1 = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen(
                  firstDataToReceive: data1,
                  secondDataToReceive: data2,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: 50,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Text('send data to home_screen'),
          ),
        )
        ],
       ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use provider. Provider let you share date to several screens and it is also more transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are asking is how to send back data from `dataEntry_screen` to `home_screen`, you can pass that data to `pop` in `dataEntry_screen` which will then be available in the `then` block of your `push` statement in `home_screen`.

In `home_screen`:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
  DataEntryScreen.id,
).then((value) {
  if(value != null) {
    setState(() {
      // Type cast to the data sent back via pop.
      var args = value as Map<String,String>;
      firstData = args['age'];
      secondData = args['height'];
    });
  }
});
```

In `dataEntry_screen` instead of `push`ing `home_screen` use `pop` to sent back data:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop({
  'age' : data1,
  'height' : data2,
});
```

To send data from `home_screen` to `dataEntry_screen`, in case you need those values, you can send `arguments` in `push` and extract it from `ModalRoute`.

In `home_screen`:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
  DataEntryScreen.id,
  arguments: {
    'age': firstData,
    'height': secondData,
  },   // arguments to be sent to DataEntryScreen
).then((value) {
  if(value != null) {
    setState(() {
      // Type cast to the data sent back via pop.
      var args = value as Map<String,String>;
      firstData = args['age'];
      secondData = args['height'];
    });
  }
});
```

and in `dataEntry_screen`:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if(data1 == null && data2 == null) {
    // Type cast to data sent via push
    var args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, String>;
    data1 = args['age'];
    data2 = args['height'];
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: Looks like that is what I am looking for but I can not try it if it working like it should. When I copy your code I get an Error: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
                      firstData = value['age'];

Comment: Whenever you are receiving value you have to typecast it the data you have sent (in this case we are sending a `Map<String, String>`. I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: works perfectly now! Thanks a lot for your help! Guess you saved me a lot of time this weekend! Great!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand it correctly.
You wish for either Age or Height and not both or all at the same time?

Following Navaneeth P's answer will probably answer most of you navigate and passing data answer.

Either use state management to decide what to build or when you do a Navigator.push() await for it and based of the args["what you need"] coming back
do a check and decide what to build.

```
_onTap() async {
  var args = await Navigator.push() 
  if(args["your variable"]!=null){ // if you pop without entering it will be null.
     setState(() {
       //something that decides what to build or clear the other variables.
       tobuild = "something"; //or even a boolean.
       age = args["age"];
    })
  }
}
```

build function

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ...
  (tobuild =="Age"|| age!=null)? // set your condition
  Text('Age:'),
      Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => DataEntryScreen(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.grey,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child:
                Text(firstDataToReceive == null ? '' : firstDataToReceive),
          ),
        ),
      ):Container(//or whatever other conditions to check);
}
```